# knockout select tag value mysticism

Tags: javascript, knockout.js, knockout-2.0

Knockout don't create value attribute if it's text representing equal option text. So selected value mystically transformed to the string type:

```
<select data-bind="foreach: opts, value: val">
    <option data-bind="text: name, value: id"></option>
</select>

var vm = {
    opts: [{id: 1, name: 'a'}, {id: 2, name: '2'}],
    val: ko.observable(1)
};
vm.val.subscribe(function (x) {
    console.log(x, typeof x);
});
ko.applyBindings(vm);
```

[test it in jsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/imbolc/aR4Px/1/)

How to can I fix this behavior?

Answer (score 2):

The [options binding](http://knockoutjs.com/documentation/options-binding.html) will preserve your types. For example:

```
<select data-bind="value: val, options: opts, optionsText: 'name', optionsValue: 'id'"></select>

<script src="knockout.js"></script>
<script>
var vm = {
    opts: [{id: 1, name: 'a'}, {id: 2, name: '2'}],
    val: ko.observable(1)
};
vm.val.subscribe(function (x) {
    console.log(x, typeof x);
});
ko.applyBindings(vm);
</script>
```

Outputs:

```
2 number
1 number
```

Comment: Thank you. But unfortunatly, I can't use this method, because I have complex logic of disabling and styling options.